# CoreImage CIColorClamp adjusting to wrong values

Tags: ios, swift, image, core-image

I'm trying CIColorClamp on an image which should just keep pixels within a specified range (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-SW42) , but when I print before and after results on a black pixel, it gives different numbers from what I did set in parameters. Here is the code:

```
let ciImage = CIImage.init(cgImage: image.cgImage!)
let filter = CIFilter("CIColorClamp")!
filter.setDefaults()
filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 0.8, y: 0.8, z: 0.8, w: 0), forKey: "inputMinComponents")
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 1, y: 1, z: 1, w: 1), forKey: "inputMaxComponents")

let outputCIImage = filter.outputImage!
let context = CIContext.init()
let outputCGImage = context.createCGImage(outputCIImage, from: outputCIImage.extent)
let outputImage = UIImage(cgImage: outputCGImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
```

This should give (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1) on a black pixel (0, 0, 0, 1), but when I print it it gives the following:

```
<CIColorClamp: inputImage=<CIImage: 0x28165d590 extent [0 0 800 160]>
inputMinComponents=[0.8 0.8 0.8 0] inputMaxComponents=[1 1 1 1]>
BEFORE 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
AFTER 0.9058823529411765, 0.9058823529411765, 0.9058823529411765, 1.0
```

Is CoreImage doing something else then just min/max? Or I don't know what else can be wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried iterating through and printing out `filter.inputKeys`? If there is something other than what you expect it would get to some sort of default value when you call `filter.setDefaults()`. That's the only code that I could see that would set an unexpected value. Perhaps try taking out that line of code since you explicitly set every inputKey you need for the filter (image, min, max) and don't need defaults for anything else.

Comment: Also, would you happen to be on a physical device or simulator?

Comment: @NSGangster yeah I tried printing inputkeys and removing defaults, but it keeps giving the same result. I run it on a real iPhone8.

Comment: Try running it on simulator? My guess (shot in the dark). Is there are a bunch of iPhone screen settings determing pixel brightness values (night redness filter, the built in light sensors in the top that auto adjust brightness). Most of these just change the amount of backlighting but there might be some that apply filters across the LED's output. You can see if it is an issue by changing one of your settings and seeing if you are getting varying values on your pixels.

Comment: let me know though, this is really interesting to me. I read through apple doc's for 45 min the other day and it looks like your doing everything for this particular filter by the book. Might be something you need to submit a bug report to apple for.

Comment: @NSGangster tried on simulator, still have the same output. IDK, it's not only with `CIColorClamp` filter, it gives wrong values with `CIColorMatrix` as well. Either I'm doing something wrong which I cannot determine, or Apple uses different algorithm & computations which gives a different result. I think more likely I'm doing something wrong as I can't find anybody else complaining about this. Maybe you can try it yourself and see if it gives the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's a color matching issue. Core Image performs color matching from input to working to output color space by default. If the color space of your input image differs from the output color space, you might get different pixel values.

Try setting up your `CIContext` in a way that is doesn't do any color matching at all:

```
let context = CIContext(options: [.workingColorSpace: NSNull(), .outputColorSpace: NSNull()])
```

For the color clamp filter this might work since it's simply clamping the values. I'm not sure if the color matrix filter requires some specific color space, though.

You can also perform a Quick Look on the  `outputCIImage` in the debugger to see a graph of operations that Core Image is actually performing on the image.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem indeed. Thank you sir!